# Determine the scrapy root directory

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I'd like to be able to read a file relative to the scrapy root directory, as described in
[the documentation](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.12/topics/commands.html#default-structure-of-scrapy-projects).

Is there a way of determining this path from inside the spider?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if scrapy is aware of where it is located on the filesystem, but in my `settings.py` i add

`PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

then in spider you can say

```
from yourscrapyprojecthere import settings

settings.PROJECT_ROOT
```

Here I have assumed my project root is wherethe settings.py file is located.  If you want to get the directory where `scrapy.cfg` is you have to go up a directory

Answer (score 8):

Very old question but for those often looking for the answer, scrapy has a built-in way of finding the project root:

`from scrapy.utils.conf import closest_scrapy_cfg`

`proj_root = closest_scrapy_cfg()`

will return the absolute path of the folder containing the scrapy.cfg file

**EDIT**:
will return the absolute path of the scrapy.cfg file for the project